# Show T-sql in Solution using entityframework

Tags: c#, sql-server, ef-core-2.2

When I used linq in entity framework and want to look at my t-sql query I used sql profiler but is there any way to see t-sql in my solution?

Comment: Well linq is not t-sql so no you can't see the t-sql in your solution. But you could run profiler and see the sql it created for you.

Comment: not sure if it meets your needs, but we use "miniprofiler" for this - in fact, you're using it right now (every SQL, redis, http, etc query on SO is tracked with miniprofiler); miniprofiler is a runtime tracker, so it is more a "in your application" thing than an "in your solution" thing

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/logging

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:  I just noticed that this question is about EF Core, so I'm not sure that this method will work.  I'll leave the answer just in case.

UPDATE 2:  Apparently the simple `Log` method described below is not quite so simple in EF Core anymore.  I found this blog entry:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dbrowne/2017/09/22/simple-logging-for-ef-core/

which goes along with @Jonesopolis comment above.

If you just want to see the T-Sql that's generated by your Entity Framework queries, then you can use the `Log` property of your data context and specify a method to call.

For example:

```
using (var ctx = new MyDataContext())
{
    ctx.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

    var results = ctx.SomeTable.Where(<some predicate here>);

    foreach (var row in results)
    {
        //Do something with row here
    }
}
```

In this example, I've set it up to call `Console.WriteLine` when it logs.  The SQL query will be shown in the Console using the `WriteLine` method.

The `Log` property is of type `Action<string>` so you can pass any method that takes a string as a parameter.